# Selenium. Как отсортировать выдачу товаров на сайте ДНС?

Tags: java, selenium

Пробую написать первый автотест на селениуме и столкнулся с проблемой - не получается отсортировать выдачу товаров на сайте ДНС. Кусок кода с помощью которого пытаюсь это сделать:
WebElement list = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#p-9aon7p"));
systemBlock.click();

Ссылка на страницу https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a8939816404e77/servery/

Answer (score 0):

Ты пытаешься привязаться к динамическому id. Он каждый раз будет генерироваться заново и твои тесты будут падать.

Вот мой xpath селектор: `//*[*[contains(text(), 'Сортировать')]]/a` для нажатия вот на этот элемент[image]

Надеюсь, что это тот который тебе нужен. А дальше уже ищешь нужный тебе фильтр, например так: `//*[contains(text(), 'По возрастанию цены')]` и нажимаешь на него.